# Right Storage to build "Last seen Products"

Tags: database-design, cassandra, redis

Wondering what would be the best Storage to build a "last seen products" feature like many of the eCommerce websites have (like Amazon, for example).

Here are some requirements:
Active Users: 200M
Last Seen Products by category (i.e.: Shoes, Eletronics, etc). There are around 500 categories
Store 10 products per category (not all categories will be visited though)
Last Seen Products must be persisted so whenever user logs back in, the list can be fetched and build.
Time to retrieve the list should be less than 100ms.

I'm thinking about ether Redis or Cassandra. Looks like both offer good capabilities for this functionality (some sort of timeline) but I'm not sure about what would be the pros and cons of each one. Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra should work well for you if your data model is built as below (from what I could understand above)

- Column family: User_Lat_Seen
- Partition key: User+category
- Additional column: Last_Seen_Items type list

Then you can easily query what items user browsed through last, for any category and also update the list whenever items change (maybe at user session end)

Comment: Thanks Gautam, That is pretty much inline to what I was thinking... My problem is that I don't know what are the benefits doing this over using Redis sorted set, for example, and partitioning the data similarly to what you proposed (partition on user+cat). That would also give me a easy way to query and update. Any thoughts on the benefits of using Cassandra over Redis?

Comment: I won't go into performance, everyone is biased these days when it comes to performance benchmarking. Moreover these are commercial products, won't come that bad in terms of perf. So next thing to think of is what are your use cases. What's your appetite for failure? C* won't fail under normal circumstances, Redis master slave architecture can. Redis has some level of transaction support in terms of locks, C* doesn't. But, do you need that? A few miss (not that should happen) in updates won't carry much weight (guess you're building some kind of recommendation engine). For me it'll be C*.

Comment: Moreover, if your app is distributed across multiple geographies, C* might give you better replication and distribution of data.